# Migration MSSQL SERVER to MY SQL with type nvarchar(max)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I trying convert MSSQL SERVER to MY SQL using ODBC, but an error occur at Bunk data transfer. 'Copy data to RDBM' fail, the log show 'Inserting Data: Data too long for column' in the table have column  type nvarchar(max). I know MY SQL dint know type nvarchar(max), it should be type text. What should i do to make Migration success? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is about 2GB in size.  You should therefore use an appropriate text type in MySQL which is large enough to cover the potentially largest entry in the column.  That would be `LONGTEXT` in MySQL, which can store about 4GB of data.

Comment: I know. But how to migration because the migration process is auto run, i cant edit. I try edit sql at step 'create target result' but it get error and ignore the table which i edited